# Как обрезать до первого символа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как обрезать до первого символа,
например:

```
var str="12323{123123}{sdfsdfsdf}";
```

результат обрезки:

```
var str1="12323"; var str2="{123123}{sdfsdfsdf}";
```

при этом до символа { значение можеть быть разной длины.
есть какие нибудь идеи? заранее спасибо!

Comment: `str.indexOf("{");` , потом обрезаете строку до этого индекса, и после, ну или как вам там нужно будет потом.

Comment: так вам обрезать нужно, или разделить строку на 2? или на несколько?

Comment: создать регулярку только для букв, на первом несовпадении обрезать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str="12323{123123}{sdfsdfsdf}";
var pos = str.indexOf('{'); // 5
var s1 = str.substr(0,pos); // 12323
var s2 = str.substr(pos); // {123123}{sdfsdfsdf}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="12323{123123}{sdfsdfsdf}";      
var strSplit = str.split('{');
var resultStr= str.substr(strSplit[0].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="12323{123123}{sdfsdfsdf}";
var str1 = str.match(/[a-z0-9]+/i)[0]; // выбор всех букв+цифр (не символов) в первую переменную
var str2 = str.substring(str.match(/[^a-z0-9]/i).index); // выбор всего, что после первого символа во вторую переменную
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант со [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var str="12323{123123}{sdfsdfsdf}";
var split = str.split(/({)/);
var str1 = split.splice(0,1);
var str2 = split.join('');

document.write('str: '+str+'<br/>');
document.write('str1: '+str1+'<br/>');
document.write('str2: '+str2+'<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str="12323{123123}{sdfsdfsdf}";
res = str.match(/([^{]+)({.*)/)
str1 = res[1]
str2 = res[2]
```